# Kinect camera freeze

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I have started developing in c# for the kinect with WPF.

When I start the sample program "colorBasics"  from  Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit, the camera works fine, but freezes after a couple of seconds.

I copied over the relevant code ( so only the code for viewing the camera ) and it also happens in my own program.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong ?

I don't get any error's.

Here is the code

```
namespace Testapp
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private KinectSensor sensor;

    private WriteableBitmap colorBitmap;

    private byte[] colorPixels;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var potentialSensor in KinectSensor.KinectSensors)
        {
            if (potentialSensor.Status == KinectStatus.Connected)
            {
                this.sensor = potentialSensor;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (null != this.sensor)
        {
            // Turn on the color stream to receive color frames
            this.sensor.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);

            // Allocate space to put the pixels we'll receive
            this.colorPixels = new byte[this.sensor.ColorStream.FramePixelDataLength];

            // This is the bitmap we'll display on-screen
            this.colorBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(this.sensor.ColorStream.FrameWidth, this.sensor.ColorStream.FrameHeight, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);

            // Set the image we display to point to the bitmap where we'll put the image data
            this.Image.Source = this.colorBitmap;

            // Add an event handler to be called whenever there is new color frame data
            this.sensor.ColorFrameReady += this.SensorColorFrameReady;

            // Start the sensor!
            try
            {
                this.sensor.Start();
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                this.sensor = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private void SensorColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        using (ColorImageFrame colorFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
        {
            if (colorFrame != null)
            {
                // Copy the pixel data from the image to a temporary array
                colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(this.colorPixels);

                // Write the pixel data into our bitmap
                this.colorBitmap.WritePixels(
                    new Int32Rect(0, 0, this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth, this.colorBitmap.PixelHeight),
                    this.colorPixels,
                    this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth * sizeof(int),
                    0);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What are your system specs?  Are you using the Kinect for Windows, or Xbox?  What is your USB controller?

Comment: I'm using the kinect for windows , can that be the cause ?

Comment: It should not be the cause.  What are your system specs and what type USB controller do you have it plugged into?  Those might be contributing to the issue.

Comment: I'm using the USB controller that was delivered with the kinect on a USB 2.0 port on a windows 8 32 bit machine

Comment: See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj663798.aspx.  Look for the information on the USB host compatibility.  Do you have any old SDKs installed?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any sort of extension with the USB cable, or is it plugged directly into the machine? I've seen what you are describing happen when the latency was too long between the sensor and the machine. In that instance it was caused by the Kinect USB cable being plugged into an extension cord.

Comment: Its plugged in directly. But after a second reboot it doesn't seem to happen again. Its weird thou, since I don't want this to happen when the application is used live.

Comment: Ok, so I guess what we are left with is a process of elimination. Since other people can run the sample, it suggests to me it might be a problem with some hardware. It's a pain, but are you able to: a) try with your machine and a different Kinect sensor b) try the same sensor with a different machine?

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem here, camera worked untill eventually just freezed and powered off, coming back after a few seconds only to repeat the freeze loop.

After many tests, my conclusion is that the issue is caused by three things:

- PC is not fast/powerful as it should be to run your code.
- Kinect is getting too hot. Even if you touch it and it's "not so hot", the sensor is very sensitive to overheat.
- The Kinect is being "disturbed" somehow. This refers to vibrations or motion physically and/or too many things in the image that resembles a human, so the soft is trying it to compute it at every frame at 30fps, this is a lot of calculus, and this fact might lead to the two other problems listed above.

This also also may cause the latency issue described by Michal