# Kinect v2 XAML performance vs WPF performance

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I've recently adquired a new MS Kinect v2 for Windows, and i'm messing with it in order to learn how it works, and how I would aproach my future ideas for it.

By now, i'm only teasing the samples that comes with the Kinect browser (Downloaded with the new SDK), using an almost new Toshiba C55 NoteBook (i5 2.5GH, 8GB RAM, NVidia 710M).

The fact is that i've tried the "Coordinate Mapping basics" sample, that comes in many forms (D2D, XAML, HTML and WPF). This sample just removes the background using the depth frame.

I've tried the all the versions so far, and the XAML sample runs very very very very slow... while the rest are running very very very smooth...

So i've tried an external code extracted from GitHub which technically does the same, also using XAML. And it also runs too slow.

Due the fact that i'm not used to develop for MS platforms, i don't know if it is really a hardware problem, or if XAML has higer requirements, and I cannot figure out why is it behaving so bad only with XAML.

I tried to find any similar questions, but didn't found any that seemed useful for my case.

I know that is probably my fault, but I don't know why... Maybe a misunderstanding of the whole setup?

The external sample I found: https://github.com/Vangos/kinect-2-background-removal

Also tried the CoordinateMapper from the same GitHub, same issue: https://github.com/Vangos/kinect-2-coordinate-mapping

Thank you all.

## UPDATE:

After developing and deploying the WPF app succefully, I'd started to check the performance of the Kinect with Windows RT, and I'd find lots of problems at memory level, W8.1 RT is slow, and does not support Kinect V2 very well, at least in my testing HW. This problems may lead to the symptoms described in this other question I found: [Kinect camera freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381734/kinect-camera-freeze)

This issue also made me note that the new Kinect V2 is VERY VERY sensitive to ambient temperature.

Hope this helps some Overflowed developars with similar problems :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Coordinate Mapper XAML and Coordinate Mapper WPF samples both use XAML.  The version marked "XAML" is a Windows Store App.  The version marked "WPF" is a Windows Desktop app.  I didn't see much of a difference on my machine between the two until I ran the [Performance and Diagnostics tools in Visual Studio 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/07/12/performance-and-diagnostics-hub-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx).  I suggest running them and creating an analysis report.  That will help you discover what exactly is causing the differences.[image: Here is an example of what that looks like in VS.]

Comment: That differentiation was what I needed. It seems that my HW feels more confortable running Desktop apps. Thank you!